# how to reference elements in a 2d array by index given in 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Say I have a 2 dimensional numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])
```

and 2 arrays for the index:

```
ind1 = np.array([0,1,1],
                [0,2,1],
                [1,2,1])

ind2 = np.array([[2,2,1],
                 [0,1,2],
                 [1,0,0]])
```

I want to create a new array `b` of the same shape as `a`, so that `b[i,j] = a[ind1[i,j],ind2[i,j]]`. How to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
b = a[ind1, ind2]
```

Output

```
[[3 6 5]
 [1 8 6]
 [5 7 4]]
```